# SSRS Calendar Matrix need to show multiple staff names

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to create a visual calendar display for reporting holidays ect. I've managed to create a matrix table that shows the day and date for a specific month. Where I'm struggling is to get it to show the 3 records i have for say the 26/09/2013. I've attached how it currently looks but added the initials in manually. That's what i want to recreate but cant figure out how to.

As it is the report only shows one record despite there being 3. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Are you using SSRS 2008 specifically or 2008R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on SSRS 2008R2, you could look to leverage the [LookupSet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function

I'm not sure how your report is implemented, but one way would be seting up a Dataset to display the calendar days, then link this up to a staff Dataset based on the date.

You would base the matrix on the calendar Dataset, then the staff expression would be something like:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!CalendarDate.Value
    , Fields!StaffDate.Value
    , Fields!StaffName.Value
    , "StaffDataset")
  , vbCrLf)
```

Which will return all staff on that day, delimited by a line break.

Another option would be to handle this when extracting the Dataset, i.e. using your preferred method to generate some sort of delimited list then displaying this in the report (perhaps updating the delimiter to a line break if required).

You can find any number of ways of creating this delimited list via T-SQL in Stack Overflow, or check out [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) article.